# trouble while checking if a number is a multiple of an other in php

Tags: php, while-loop, modulo

I have some trouble while checking if a number is a multiple of an other. For my website, I have to do all queries in functions.

to be simple,

I have a query that looks for some informations in my database. and I do display that informations in some divs.  If the number of results is a multiple of 3, it is display like I do not want :

[image]

What I want to do, is if, the number of result is a multiple of 3, then I add an other div but in style visibility hidden, so it would be good visual

[image]

For doing that I've tried to return in my function the mysql_num_rows result and to work with that number in my loop.

my function is like that

```
function fetchListeHome($id_cat) {
    $query = "SELECT `spb_maison_kit_detail_reference`, `spb_maison_kit_detail_superficie`, 
        `spb_maison_kit_detail_prix`, `spb_maison_kit_detail_url_img`, `spb_maison_kit_detail_id`  
        FROM `spb_maison_kit_detail`
        WHERE `spb_maison_kit_detail_id_categorie` = '{$id_cat}'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    $result['num_rows'] = $num_rows;
    return $result;
}
```

if I can have the number of results, so I can check in the loop, the last iteration, and check if it is a multiple of 3, if that is the case, I can display my hidden div.

Actualy this return to me an error, so I can not work with the number of rows

below is the error displayed

```
Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array
```

Anykind of help will be much appreciated.

Comment: What is the exact line giving that error? That means that you're doing something like `$obj['key']` when it should be `$obj->key`, and I don't see that here.

Comment: the exact line is that one   $result['num_rows'] = $num_rows; I'm not working with an object but with an array.

Comment: Oh I see; `$result` is a resource, not the row result values. See Kypros' answer; you need to *get* the row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to fetch the results of that query before you have access to the `$result` as an `array` with something like this:

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result); // add this line
$row['num_rows'] = $num_rows;
return $row;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an array and then return it

```
function fetchListeHome($id_cat) {
    $resultArray = array();
    $query = "SELECT `spb_maison_kit_detail_reference`, `spb_maison_kit_detail_superficie`, 
        `spb_maison_kit_detail_prix`, `spb_maison_kit_detail_url_img`, `spb_maison_kit_detail_id`  
        FROM `spb_maison_kit_detail`
        WHERE `spb_maison_kit_detail_id_categorie` = '{$id_cat}'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

    $resultArray array(
        'result'   => $result,
        'num_rows' => $num_rows
    )
    return $resultArray;
}
```

Comment: `$result` is still referencing a *resource*, not the row.